# how can i unregister receiver in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i got this error thing `Leaked Intent Receiver that was originally registered here`, but the apps is still up and running even with that error kind of thing, what causes that error ? and does this affects the apps ?

here's what im trying to do :

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPendingIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredPendingIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> mSMSMessage = sms.divideMessage(message);
        for (int i = 0; i < mSMSMessage.size(); i++) {
            sentPendingIntents.add(i, sentPI);
            deliveredPendingIntents.add(i, deliveredPI);
        }
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, mSMSMessage,
                sentPendingIntents, deliveredPendingIntents);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "SMS sending failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
}
```

tnx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

- If you have registered the receiver in the `onCreate` then unregister it in it's `onDestroy` method.
- If you have registered the receiver in the `onResume` then unregister it in it's `onPause` method.
- If you have registered the receiver in the `onStart` then unregister it in it's `onStop` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely because the `Activity` you are calling `sendSMS` from has exited, but that is the context in which you have registered your receivers as anonymous inner classes. You'll need to pull those receivers out, or retain references to them and unregister them in your `onPause()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the receiver is being registered inside an activity and not on the manifest, you need to unregister it onPause or onStop

```
 public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (myReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        }
```

I forgot to mention that you should created the BroadcastReceiver inside an inner class such as

```
  private class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Add your code here
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if i dont do the unregister thing..does that error can cause a problem to the app ?

Comment: It crashes the app in most devices depending of how dependent your app is to the BroascastReceiver, maybe you might want to create the broadcast receiver in the manifest instead of programmatically, that will remove the hassle of having to unregistered it by yourself.